# Advice to modify code to show multiple xpaths (PHP)

Tags: php, html, class, xpath

I'm using this test code on a site to learn how to do it. I'm attempting to basically web scrape everything contained in a specific div class, and echo it back on another site. This below is successfully accomplishing this with only the first div class displayed on the site, whereas I'd like it to display all. The below code spits out this result: string(107) " DJIA 21182.53 +8.84(0.04%) "

```
<?php 

 $doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.nbcnews.com/business');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//div[@class='market']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
var_dump($entries->item(0)->textContent);

?>
```

The source code however has these entries as well:

```
    <div class="market">
            <span class="market_item market_name">DJIA</span>
            <span class="market_item market_price">21182.53</span>
            <span class="market_item market_price  is-positive ">
            +8.84(0.04%)</span>
          </div>
          <div class="market">
            <span class="market_item market_name">NASDAQ</span>
            <span class="market_item market_price">6321.76</span>
            <span class="market_item market_price  is-positive ">
            +24.38(0.39%)</span>
          </div>
          <div class="market">
            <span class="market_item market_name">S&amp;P 500</span>
            <span class="market_item market_price">2433.79</span>
            <span class="market_item market_price  is-positive ">
            +0.65(0.03%)</span>
          </div>
```

Thoughts on what I need to modify in order to show all 3 of these? Guessing it could have something to do with the item(O), but when I modify that I break the code.
Second thing I'd like very much to change, is to stop the "string(___)" being displayed before the actual echo text.

Really appreciate it!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$entries` is object you can iterate over:

```
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces
}
```